# How to fix sbt's [warn] Skipped generating '<exclusion/>' for dependency?

Tags: sbt, dependency-management, scalaz7

When I run `makePom` in sbt I get:

```
[warn] Skipped generating '<exclusion/>' for org.scalaz#*. Dependency exclusion should have both 'org' and 'module' to comply with Maven POM's schema.
[warn] Skipped generating '<exclusion/>' for com.jolbox#*. Dependency exclusion should have both 'org' and 'module' to comply with Maven POM's schema.
```

What's the easiest way to fix this problem so that the correct exclusions get generated?

---

The following **does not work** - it breaks the scalaz exclusion rule - I presume because scalaz 7 is composed of multiple jars:

```
ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scalaz", name="scalaz-core")
```

and

```
ExclusionRule(organization = "com.jolbox", name="bonecp")
```

Comment: Now `sbt` seems to be in a weird inconsistent state whereby the project sometimes depends on Scalaz 6 (which is what I want), but when I try to publish it, it depends on Scalaz 7 because the new exclusion rule doesn't work properly! E.g. if I do `show compile:full-classpath`, it shows only Scalaz 6 as a dependency.

Comment: Ah, sorry - the relevant exclusion rule only applies to the `test` code, which explains why `show compile:full-classpath` looked OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the multiple jars that's the problem for the scalaz exclusion rule - it's that there is no `%%` in an `ExclusionRule`, so I needed to explicitly add the Scala version for any dependencies which have them in their module name, like so:

```
ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scalaz", name="scalaz-core_2.10")
```

Comment: That seems like an important thing to note in the documentation on excludes.  Perhaps you could submit a pull request or file an issue for it?