# Skipped generating '<exclusion/>' for com.google#*. Dependency exclusion should have both 'org' and 'module' to comply with Maven POM's

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following lines in my build

```
val hadoop = "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.7.3" excludeAll(
   ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),
   ExclusionRule(organization= "com.google"))
val hive = "org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "2.1.0" excludeAll(
   ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j"),
   ExclusionRule(organization= "com.google")
   )
```

I am getting this warning when I try to generate an assembly

```
Skipped generating '<exclusion/>' for com.google#*. Dependency exclusion should have both 'org' and 'module' to comply with Maven POM's
```

I googled and found this solution for the problem

[How to fix sbt's [warn] Skipped generating '<exclusion/>' for dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189211/how-to-fix-sbts-warn-skipped-generating-exclusion-for-dependency)

The solution states that I should specify the scala version (since there is no %% in the dependency definition).

However in my case the dependency does not really target a specific scala version

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/2.7.3

and so I am not sure what version should I put in the name attribute.

Comment: The warning said `Dependency exclusion should have both 'org' and 'module'` so have you tried adding the **module** name ?

Comment: there was no module, but I did see a name. when I specified the name, the warning disappeared... even though I am not sure if it actually generated the exclusion or not.

Comment: tested a little more. it seems just specifying the name works. and makes the warning disappear.